# wevtutil Failed to export remote log

Tags: windows-event-log

I use:

`wevtutil epl Application c:\logs\application.evtx`

And export Envenlog. But when export a remote machine using:

`wevtutil epl Application c:\logs\application.evtx /r:remote-machine`

Don't work. I get and error.
`Failed to export log Application. Access is denied.`

But my user is administrator in my current machine and remote-machine.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you working with **domain join** servers or **workgroups** servers ?  What is the result of the following commands ?

```
wevtutil epl /r:<remote_computer_name> /u:<target_computer_name>\<user_name> /p:<password>
wevtutil epl /r:<remote_computer_name> /u:<domain_name>\<user_name> /p:<password>
```

I also suggest to :

- Connect to the administrative share (C$) of your target server from your source server using your administrator account and see if this is successful. If not, you may need to review your account rights
- Check if you don't have any restrictions on your Event Viewer (per default there is no reason)
- Check if account is not blocked or expired
- Check your administrator(s) credentials if you are in a workgroup

On my side, I have tested your command in a domain and export was done without problems (see image below).

[image: wevutil export]

Comment: Sorry... I don't understand... but your code work and export and create the file in remote machine.